# elastic beanstalk changing domain name with route53

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-route53

So I purchased a new domain on Amazon server, and that domain is in hosted zone. and in hosted zone, I created new record set. 
www.mysite.com. and used CNAME and in value I put the domain name elastic beanstalk provides http://mysite.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

But when I go to mysite.com, nothing shows up. Can someone please point me out what I did wrong?

Comment: Navigating to http://mysite.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ should show the content you are expecting. Do you need to do an EB release? Also check if there are instances within the Elastic Load Balancer.

Comment: @SulemanC thanks for the response, i see the content when I go there(with elastic domain) but I don't see it when when I go to mysite.com?

Comment: mysite.com is different from www.mysite.com so make sure you are using the CNAME you actually defined (www.mysite.com) in Route 53 to access your site

Comment: thank you, now it works but on Evaluate Target Health, it says No. do you know what it indicates?

Comment: Glad it worked. It is a setting to check the health of the alias. You can read more about it here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-complex-configs.html#dns-failover-complex-configs-eth-no

Comment: thanks, I'm reading about this right now...not sure why I get no tho